# Lucas-like series with two first values chosen

Tags: python, fibonacci

I want to make a function that would construct Lucas- (or Fibonacci-) like sequence. I want to be able to choose two first numbers and then to make the next one be a sum of two previous ones. The way I was thinking about that problem was:

```
def lucaslike(a, b, n):
    x = [a, b]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        return x.append(x[i-1] + x[i-2])
```

But when trying to use it `print(lucaslike(3, 6, 10))`, I get that the function is not defined.

I would like to be able to tell the function to produce Lucas-like sequence of n=10 terms, when for example two first values are a=3 and b=6. So that the output should be: `[3, 6, 9, 15, 24, 39, ...]`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `I get that the function is not defined` - cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this :

```
def lucaslike(a, b, n):
    x = [a, b]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        x.append(x[i-1] + x[i-2])
    return x
```

Like that, this function will return only at the end the whole list of Lucas_like sentence.

`lucaslike(3,6,10)` or `print(lucaslike(3,6,10))` will return `[3, 6, 9, 15, 24, 39, 63, 102, 165, 267, 432]`

Comment: You don't have to write `return(x)` instead of `return x`, both work.
Also, the indentation on this answer is incorrect.